# generate a graph with matplotlib from excel

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a graph with matplotlib, but my code is not working. Can anyone take a look at it please? The code is posted below. Sorry for the grammar mistakes in this post, English isn't my first language, but I am working on it.

The instruction for the code is to create a function scatter_plot(filename, stat) and it take in a x and y value from the table provided. The x is the days and y is the stat of whatever the user wants(ex. Max  temp,Normal recipitation,Record precipitation and etc).

[image: Excel information]

```py
def scatter_plot(filename, stat):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        header_row = f.readline()
        header_row=header_row.strip()
        header_row=header_row.split()
    info=np.loadtext(filename,delimiter=',',skiprows=1)
    x_values=[]
    y_values=[]
    for row in info:
        for i in range(len(row)):          
            x_values.append([2])
            y_values.append([i])
    
    plt.plot(x_values,y_values, 'gs')
    plt.xlabel('Julian Days')
    plt.ylabel(stat)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Hi Jennifer, are you familiar with python? You intendents are wrong. And you must vall your function.

Comment: I think the intendents are right. Stackflow for some reason isn't letting me edit my code when I paste. How do you vall a function?

Comment: The.B had a typo, they mean call a function, as  `scatter_plot()` is never called in your example code.